# PFFacebookUtils login results as invalid scope in same cases

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

---

I´m using the Parse iOS SDK and I found that when you do:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"basic_info"];
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) { }];
```

It works well in some devices. But in anothers, included de iPhone Simulator you need to change "basic_info" for the new permission "public_info". Then it works in the other devices and in the iPhone but not in the first ones...

I don't have an idea how to solve this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I discovered you don´t need to specify neither basic_info or public_profile, just leave the permissions array empty and it will work.

Now I'm more confused than before but at least it works.